# App has stopped when run a service in different thread

Tags: android, android-service

I added android:process in manifest file, and then i get app has stopped popup while loading up apk. Service doesn't load but the rest of thing is running okay.

```
<service
            android:name=".smsReceiveService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":myProcess"
            android:isolatedProcess="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: check my ans and ask me in case of any query

Comment: Can you attach the crash log here?

Comment: Nothing in crash logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add permission in manifiest file at top
like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ncrypted.otp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

than your receiver sevrcice in application tag like this

```
  <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

than handle run time permision for lolipop virsions like this

```
private void requestSmsPermission() {
    String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
    int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] permission_list = new String[1];
        permission_list[0] = permission;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done all this. It was working fine before adding process tag in manifest. Added manifest tag to run this even when app is closed.